# How to solve report date and time on report

Tags: c#, datetime, rdlc

When I working locale current date and time display correct in rdlc report. but upload .rdlc on server date and time display different.

example current date and time in local report is : **10 Jun 2014 5:01 AM**
Example Current upload file in server Outpunt is: **08 Jun 2014 10:17 PM**

Option setting is :

[image]

How to solve this issue.

Comment: different timezone? regional retting?

Comment: @ Infer-On :- but. how? give me so example.

Comment: probably your machine have different timezone or regional setting, check with your IT admin to check the regional setting/timezone of production server

Answer (score 1):

```
=TimezoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(Globals!ExecutionTime.ToUniversalTime(),
            TimeZoneInfo.CreateCustomTimeZone("client", new TimeSpan(06, 00, 00),
            "client", "client"))
```

Here `TimeSpan` 06 means (GMT+06:00), "client" is a simple string just to specify name